# Unable to read/ retrieve non-standard/Custom HTTP headers in java

Tags: http

I am using  getAllHeaders() (HttpClient Java API ) to access response headers but I would able to see only following standard headers

```
Date = Mon, 08 Jun 2015 06:57:31 GMT
Server = Apache
Pragma = no-cache
Cache-Control = no-cache, no-store
Expires = Wed, 31 Dec 1969 19:00:00 EST
Content-Type = text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

I am unable to read or see custom headers like **userAuthToken** from HTTP response.
Please suggest approach to read or retrieve non standard or custom headers from http response.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Standard headers areContent-Length = 1293
Keep-Alive = timeout=15, max=100
Connection= Keep-Alive
X-Powered-By = Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1
Accept-Ranges = bytes
ETag = W/"17094-1432102910000"
Last-Modified = Wed, 20 May 2015 06:21:50 GMT

Comment: Try adding code samples to make your question clearer in terms of exactly what you have tried. Also provide exceptions if there are any

Comment: To read http header i am using code from following link http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-http-request-header-in-java/   but using given code i am able to read only standard HTTP headers not non- standard HTTP headers(for example custom headers pqr=asjjajsjah) from HTTP response. Any code or help to read non standard HTTP headers will be helpful.